# Enabling Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on Apache for 2 domain names

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I tried to get Let's Encrypt certificates for both my www and non-www domain names, then redirect all the requests to https://www.afa-advisory.com/.

I installed certbot on my OVH VPS, then I tried many attempts to get both certificates:

1) I tried an all-in-one command: 
certbot --apache -d afa-advisory.com -d www.afa-advisory.com

2) I tried the domain names separately in two commands:
certbot --apache -d afa-advisory.com 
certbot --apache -d www.afa-advisory.com

3) I tried expanding the first SSL certificate.

The problem is that I always get an invalid certificate for my root domain:

Invalid Common Name: Default Company Ltd

Comment: Check the certificate chain in your browser.   It seems you may have a different certificate for that domain.

Comment: I checked it, the common name is not correct, but that's what was generated with certbot, may be a bug ?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but did you try to generate certificate for both URL's?, by example:

```
  sudo certbot --apache -d mydomain.com,www.mydomain.com
```

I dont use:

```
  sudo certbot --apache -d mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com
```

Because  this last one,  generate different certificate for each hostname.

Comment: I'm confused. Both of those commands look the same. Are you suggesting that it is the correct command or the wrong command?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm so sorry, it was badly written, thank you for report it

Comment: stange... for automating hosting management I use `certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path /some/path -d domaine.com -d other.domaine.com,some.other.com`  and it generates a single cert as this way I am sure it generates the cert in the folder /etc/letsencrypt/live/domaine.com